# python and ldap via SSL

Tags: python, ssl, ldap, ldap-query, ldapconnection

I try to query an Active Directory Server with python which works fine. But now I don't want to send my credentials unencrypted on the wire, so I'd like to use LDAPs. 
Is there an easy way to do this? All I found till now was that I had to add this option:

```
l.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_CACERTFILE,'/path/to/my/Ca.pem')
```

But I actually don't want to get the CA cert or a correct cert and verify that as well. Sure, from a security perspective I should verify that my communication partner is the correct one, but I don't care on my internal network and want this just easier to handle. 
If I just change the LDAP URL from ldap to ldaps I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ldap-to-sql.py", line 21, in <module>
    bind = l.simple_bind_s(USERNAME, PASS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 214, in simple_bind_s
    msgid = self.simple_bind(who,cred,serverctrls,clientctrls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 208, in simple_bind
    return self._ldap_call(self._l.simple_bind,who,cred,RequestControlTuples(serverctrls),RequestControlTuples(clientctrls))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 106, in _ldap_call
    result = func(*args,**kwargs)
ldap.SERVER_DOWN: {'info': 'SSLHandshake() failed: misc. bad certificate (-9825)', 'desc': "Can't contact LDAP server"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was doing some tests with a Samba4 DC and python ldap module and i've done this example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import ldap, ldapurl, subprocess, sys, shlex, os

GrupoLDAP = "Domain Users" #Grupo a recuperar
CACert = '/etc/cert/ca.cert.pem' #Certificado CA

ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_CACERTFILE, CACert)
ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, ldap.OPT_X_TLS_HARD)

proto = 'ldaps' #Protocolo
server = 'domain.com' #Dirección del servidor (mismo nombre del Certificado)
port = 636 #Puerto seguro para ldaps

try:
    url = ldapurl.LDAPUrl(urlscheme=proto, hostport="%s:%s" % (server, str(port))).initializeUrl()
    ldap_obj = ldap.initialize(url)
    ldap_obj.simple_bind_s('user@domain.com','PassWord')

    base = 'OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com' #Ruta y UO del grupo

    scope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE

    query = '(&(objectClass=person)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))'

    res_attrs = ['sAMAccountName', 'cn']
    #res_attrs = ['*']
    res = ldap_obj.search_s(base, scope, query, res_attrs)
except ldap.LDAPError as Error:
    print "Ha ocurrido un error al conectar o realizar la query al servidor LDAP:\n\n%s" % Error
    sys.exit(1)
```

The certificate needs the FQDN in CN and be signed by the CA cert to avoid Certs error. Was working until I've added a second DC to same FQDN but if you only have one DC it should work.
I don't know how it works on a Windows LDAP, but seems to be similar.

Greetings!!

Answer (score 1):

2 years ago, hm.... ok, may be too late.

however, try below codes. works for me for python/ldap/active directory/TLS.

```
import ldap
ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, ldap.OPT_X_TLS_ALLOW)
l = ldap.initialize("ldaps://ad.xxx.yyy:636")
l.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
l.simple_bind_s("xxx\username", 'pw')
l.search_s('DC=AD,DC=XXX,DC=YYY', ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, '(samaccountname=username)', ['displayname'])
```