# Python-ldap can connect to active directory from python console but not application

Tags: python, django, ssl, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to connect to an active directory using Python-ldap library.
I have the following bind code:

```
def bind_connection():
    ldap_password = *******
    ldap_url = 'ldaps://*******:636
    ldap_login = "CN=***, CN=Users, DC=***, DC=local"
    ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, ldap.OPT_X_TLS_NEVER)
    l = ldap.initialize(ldap_url)
    l.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
    l.set_option(ldap.OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3)
    l.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS, ldap.OPT_X_TLS_DEMAND)
    l.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_DEMAND, True)
    l.set_option(ldap.OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 255)
    l.simple_bind_s(ldap_login, ldap_password)
    return l
```

Importing and running this in the python console works fine. I can search, create users, etc with this bind.

Trying to use this class in an Django application returns :

> ```
> SERVER_DOWN: {'info': 'SSLHandshake() failed: misc. bad certificate
> (-9825)', 'errno': 2, 'desc': "Can't contact LDAP server"}
> ```

All code is being run from the same development environment.
Why would it work in one instance and not the other?

Comment: You might want to set the truststore path in the code. Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29296279/python-and-ldap-via-ssl

Answer (score 0):

Was able to figure it out. I found this in the demo supplied with the python-ldap library.

```
# Force libldap to create a new SSL context (must be last TLS option!)
l.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_NEWCTX,0)
```

A new SSL context must be created, and this option will do that.